# Are there other proofs of Fermat's theorem other than Wiles?

Tags: alternative-proof

Andrew Wiles proved Fermat's last theorem in 1994, 23 years ago. I studied the proof, and I was wondering if anyone have provided a shorter proof or even shortcuts since then?

Comment: The "GM" section of the Arxiv is full of them :-)

Comment: Thanks, any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "proof of FLT" was a corollary of Wiles' proof of the Taniyama-Shimura-Weil conjecture, now called the Modularity Theorem. As far as I know, there has been no peer reviewed alternative proof.

The T-S conjecture is today considered to be much more significant than proving FLT. So, it's not a mainstream activity many reputable mathematicians will devote time to.

This is of course not to say that a proof couldn't arise out of the blue. But the overwhelming general consensus is that Fermat did not have a short proof.